# How can I get the value of this object?

Tags: json, angular, mongodb, typescript

I am using **Angular** 8 to get the data out of a radio input. When I send that data to **Node** then to **Mongodb** database, it is not register, and it appear like this in the db collection:

```
"__v" : 0
```

The output of the data that is being sent from **Angular** is: `{ type: administrator }`, what I want to register in the db is only the word `adminstrator`. The **Node** console shows an error because of the object that is passed to the db when it expects a string value.

The Angular template is this:

```
<br>
<div class="w3-panel w3-border w3-margin" style="width: 500px; height: 550px">

        <label class="w3-text-blue"><h2>New User</h2></label>
        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Name and Last Name</b></label><br>
           <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border" [(ngModel)]="name" ><br>

        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>User</b></label><br>
           <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border" [(ngModel)]="user"><br>

        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Password</b></label><br>
           <input type="password" class="w3-input w3-border" [(ngModel)]="password"><br>

        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Confirm Password</b></label><br>
           <input type="password" class="w3-input w3-border" [(ngModel)]="confirm"><br>

        <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Type of User</b></label><br>

        <form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="sendRadio(myForm.value)" >
            <input id="administrator" type="radio" name="type" class="w3-radio" value="administrator" ngModel>
               <label for="administrador">Administrador</label> <br>
            <input id="normal" type="radio" name="type" class="w3-radio" value="normal" ngModel>
               <label for="normal">Moderador</label>
     <br><br>
        <button type="submit" (click)="createUser(user, password, name)" class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-green">Create</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-round-xxlarge w3-red">Clean Fields</button>
</form>

</div>
```

The component's typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonService } from '../_services/person.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;
  password: any;
  confirm: any;
  name: any;
  type: string;

  constructor(private ps: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendRadio(value: any) {
    this.type = value;
    console.log(this.type);  // <--- this outputs { type: administrator }
  }

  createUser(userU, userPassword, userName) {
    if (this.password === this.confirm) {
       if (this.password.length > 0 && this.confirm.length > 0) { 
          this.ps.createUser(userU, userPassword, userName, this.type);
          } else {
            console.log('Password has to match and be completed');
            }
    }else {
        console.log('Password does not match');   

    }
  }
}
```

The service to send the data (PersonService):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createUser(userU, userPassword, userName, userType: string) {
    const obj = {
      user: userU,
      password: userPassword,
      name: userName,
      type: userType
    };
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}/createUser`, obj)
    .subscribe(res => console.log('User has been created'));
  }
```

Comment: whats wrong if you just do `this.type = value.type;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in

```
console.log(this.type.type);
```

because you need the *value* of the key for `type`. This prints out 'administrator' and you can pass that to your backend node.

Comment: Thank you!! now I can get the value.